# Unable to download file from AWS using Python script

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3

I am trying to download a file from AWS S3 server to my local. However, when I tried to run the below query I get an error saying "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:"

---

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

ACCESS_KEY_ID = '###'
ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = '###'
BUCKET_NAME = 'abc.helper'
FILE_NAME = 'k.png'


data = open(FILE_NAME, 'rb')

#### S3 Connect:
s3 = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,
    config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
)

#### Image download:
s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(FILE_NAME, '/Users/kevin/desktop');

print ("Done")
```

---

I have hidden the Access Key and Secret ID fr obvious reasons. Could anyone help me find where the error is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you

```
import boto3
import botocore

BUCKET_NAME = 'my-bucket' # replace with your bucket name
KEY = 'my_image_in_s3.jpg' # replace with your object key

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

try:
    s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(KEY, 'my_local_image.jpg')
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
        print("The object does not exist.")
    else:
        raise
```

This link will help you more [s3-example-download-file](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html)

Comment: Thanks a few questions on this code. We have not passed our credentials how does it work. Next what is an object key, where can I find it. Sorry for a novice reply as I am learning these for the first time..

Comment: Object key is your file name which file you wants to download.